# Is it possible to identify lego bricks with python and rename them according to their type

Tags: python, outliner

So basically, I have a bunch of Lego bricks in my blender scene, they have different sizes, colours, etc. I was wondering if it was possible to set up some kind of detection system in python, where it can see the dimensions of each brick and rename the bricks according to those aspects.

for example if I had a 2 x 4 x 6 plate brick, python would recognise that it is a plate of that dimension and rename it to '2x4x6_plate.'

So, could it be done?[image]

Comment: You can check their dimensions and rename them accordingly

Comment: This might help get you started: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-iterate-through-objects-in-a-scene/519045/3

Answer (score 1):

```py
import bpy

for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    dimensions = object.dimensions
    if dimensions.x == 2 and dimensions.y == 4 and dimensions.z == 6:
        object.name = '2x4x6_plate'
        if object.type == 'MESH':
            object.data.name == '2x4x6_plate'
```

Comment: thank you very much:)